# sql why cant I select two of the same colum and search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

cant I SELECT two of the same column. Here is the website:

```
 http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where_and
```

There is an sql command to run from and I am trying to select from two countries at the same time. Here is the code:

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany' AND Country='Germany';
```

How can I select from two countries??

Comment: Use the `IN()` clause: `WHERE Country IN('country 1', 'country 2', ...)`

Comment: Try looking up truth tables in discrete math.  There are several youtube videos that will help you to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using OR operator as it will look for either one

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Germany' OR Country='UK';
```

to do a wildcard lookup for the country name you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE '%Germany%' OR Country LIKE '%UK%';
```

you can even use an IN()

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN('Germany', 'UK');
```

If you look at that W3Schools example it has `Country = something AND city = something` city and country are both inside one row for the table. when you only have country you can't use AND because AND means they both have to match.

**VISUALIZE THE DATA:**

```
 +-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
 |CustomerID |  CustomerNam |  City  |  Country |
 +-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
 |   1       |  billy       | Berlin |  Germany |
 |   2       |  bob         | London |  UK      |
 +-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

both Berlin AND Germany are in a row in the table and correspond to billy.. 
if you looked for `country = Germany AND country = UK` that would fail as there is no country that is two countries in the database

Comment: because AND means that the country name for EACH row MUST be both names which can never be true

Comment: @user3781326 of course! when you can please dont forget to accept the answer :)